# xargs: how do I ignore error code 255 and continue iterating?

Tags: linux, loops, unix, xargs, exit-code

I am running this:

```
cat Samples.txt | xargs -P 8 -I {} ./idk.sh {}
```

where Samples.txt is feeding idk.sh names of directories and files.
Unfortunately, some portion of the samples dont have the requested folder and/or file.
How do I get xargs to ignore these cases and continue iterating over the remaining samples?

Answer (score 1):

I also found an alternative answer to those provided and I hope the community can upvote the best one:

```
xargs -P 8 -i sh -c "./idk.sh {} || true"
```

I dont know how this one works tho, I just copied it... an explanation or resources to learn would be appreciated as I did not see it in any xargs cheat sheets I found.

Answer (score 0):

Change the script `idk.sh` to detect the argument doesn't exist and not exit with 255 in that case.

Or, create a script that wraps `idk.sh` and doesn't exit with 255.

```
./idk.sh "$@"
x=$?
[ $x -eq 255 ] && exit 254
exit $x
```

Or just suppress all errors to make the script simpler, and then supply it as part of the command given to xargs:

```
xargs -P 8 -I {} sh -c './idk.sh {} ; exit 0'
```

Comment: for the wrapping solution:
Is it that I have a script (e.g. wrapped.sh) that contains the code you shared? aka calling idk.sh and tells it not to exit with 255?

Comment: " sh -c ' ./idk.sh {} :exit 0' " I am interested in what sh -c is and ; exit 0

Comment: yes, that's the idea.  `sh -c 'commands...'`, will run `commands...` as as if it was a shell script.  `exit 0` will cause the script to exit with code 0.  Otherwise it exits with the code of the last command.  The `;` is used to separate commands.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat Samples.txt | xargs -P 8 -I {} find . -name {} -exec ./idk.sh '{}' \;
```

One option may be to xargs to find and -exec.

Comment: That won't work if any of the names contain directories or are absolute paths.